# image change with .attr() doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the img on click.
this is my html code:

```
<div id ="Nl">
   <img id="imgNl" src="images/Nl.jpg">
</div>
```

this is the awnser I found:

```
<script>
        $('#Nl').click(function(){
            $('imgNl').attr('src', 'images/smiley.jpg');
        });
 </script>
```

It doesn't work. what did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems that you forgot to set `#` before `imgNl` in the selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the id selector '#'

```
$('#imgNl').attr('src', 'images/smiley.jpg');
```

for more info on selectors [refer this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
        $('#Nl').click(function(){
            $('#imgNl').attr('src', 'images/smiley.jpg');
        });
 </script>
```

missed the `#` for id

Answer (score 0):

your correct script is :-

```
    <script>
         $('#Nl').click(function(){
         $('#imgNl').attr('src', 'images/smiley.jpg');
       });
    </script>
```